# Is Navicat's "query time" (shown under query results) inaccurate?

Tags: mysql, navicat

When I run a query in Navicat (Windows, via SSH tunnel to my webserver's mysql instance), it tells me that the "query time" was 0.486s.

But if I click on the "profile" tab, the longest item is "sending data", which at 0.166s is apparently "95%".

Indeed if I run the same query from my mysql cli on my webserver it takes approximately 0.17 seconds.

So where does the 0.486 come from? Is this a known fault?  I seem to be able to replicate a similar discrepancy with any query that I try.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the query time also includes the overhead from the remote connection.
If you execute a query directly on the mysql server (no remote connections) the returned timing is about the same as the 'time' you see in the 'message' tab in navicat. That is the real query time without any overhead.

Keep in mind that the query in your application will probably have some overhead unlike your direct active connection to mysql in cli.